# update gnome in centos 6.4

Tags: centos, gnome

my current version of gnome is : 2.28.2 and I want to update it to version 3.
is there a way to do that ?
I searched a lot about this problem , but all of the results is about installing gnome on a minimal centos .
Im using centos 6.4

Answer (score 1):

There is no practical and reasonable way to do this. Wait for RHEL7 or 
switch to Fedora if you want Gnome3.